# Inserting "/"[backslash] in place of " "[space] while inserting HTML

Tags: html

Are these two considered equal?

<body/onload=prompt()>

<body onload=prompt()>

Are there any other variations of inserting spaces within the HTML tag?

Thanks

Comment: '/' is a forward slash, not a backslash.

Answer (score 2):

That's a forward slash, not a backslash and they are not considered equal. `<body/onload=prompt()>` is an error (although browsers may recover from it).

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-0):

> If there are to be any attributes in the next step, there must first be one or more space characters.

[and](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character):

> The space characters, for the purposes of this specification, are U+0020 SPACE, "tab" (U+0009), "LF" (U+000A), "FF" (U+000C), and "CR" (U+000D).

A `/` is U+002F which isn't among them.